# How to store MXNet graph visualization as image in a file?

Tags: mxnet

According to [this](https://mxnet.incubator.apache.org/how_to/visualize_graph.html) page, MXNet computation graph can be visualized using `mx.viz.plot_network(net)`.

But that only works on Jupyter notebook. How do I do it without Jupyter notebook? Is it possible to save the visualization as a image in a file?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`mx.viz.plot_network` returns a `graphviz.dot.Digraph` object and it can be rendered to file like any other `Digraph` object.

Here is an example:

```
# Store the Digraph in a variable
graph = mx.viz.plot_network(net)

# Pick an image format from this list: http://www.graphviz.org/doc/info/output.html
graph.format = 'png'

# Choose a filename and render the image.
graph.render('graph')
```

Above code will render the graph in 'graph.png' in the current directory.